# Vector icons in OL3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I want to use drawn vector icons as markers, so they keep their size when the image is scaled, but I can still color and style them. If I use image in style, like so:

```
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon( ({
        src: 'img.png'
      }))
    });

var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]),
});
iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);
```

It looks like I have to specify an image. Is there a way to spec a vector object, say geoJson or SVG?

Or do I need to spec the feature some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that image can be vectors as well as a raster icon:

```
var style=new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({                                    
            radius: 100,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: #ff0000" })                         
            })
      });

var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
     geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]),
     });

iconFeature.setStyle(style);
```